# Total Download Allowed Option Missing In Opencart 2.0.3.1

Tags: opencart2.x

I am unable to see Total Download Allowed option In Catalog >> Downloads.

I am using opencart 2.0.3.1

I am just seeing

**Download Name (required Field)**, 
**File Name + Upload Button**, 
**Mask**

I checked opencart 1.5.0.6... in mysql database table, there is "remaining" column is present "oc_download" table which is missing in opencart 2.0.3.1

How can i do it ? after adding this column, which files I will needed to edit in Admin Folder, Catalog folder, + any other folders ?

Answer (score 0):

> For admin side

1. Modify `download_form.tpl` and add `total downloads allowed` textbox.
2. Modify your table and controller and model file

> For front end

Considering after you have properly modified admin side, you have to modify two files in your catalog folder which is `account/download` controller file and `account/download` model file. In controller you have to put a code when file download function executes. In older version of `opencart` there is a line which updates download table which is `$this->model_account_download->updateRemaining($this->request->get['order_download_id']);` Refere this link [For controller](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/v1.5.6.x/upload/catalog/controller/account/download.php) and this link [For model](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/v1.5.6.x/upload/catalog/model/account/download.php).